# Show pop-up/modal for confirmation before form submission

Tags: html, angularjs

With AngularJS, how can we display a popup for rechecking and confirming the input values entered on clicking the submit button, before submitting the form data?

Comment: I guess what you are looking for, in terms of UI, is called a "modal"? you can find some examples here https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/  Search for modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `Uib modal`. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($uibModal, $log, $document) {
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.animationsEnabled = true;
  $ctrl.name = "Manikandan";

  $ctrl.open = function (size, parentSelector) {
    var parentElem = parentSelector ? 
      angular.element($document[0].querySelector('.modal-demo ' + parentSelector)) : undefined;
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      size: size,
      appendTo: parentElem,
      resolve: {
        values: function () {
          return $ctrl.name;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function () {
      $ctrl.msg = "Submitted";
      $ctrl.suc = true; 
    }, function(error) {
      $ctrl.msg = 'Cancelled';
      $ctrl.suc = false; 
    });
  };
});


angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($uibModalInstance, values) {
 var $ctrl = this;
 $ctrl.name= values;
  $ctrl.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close('ok');
  };

  $ctrl.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl as $ctrl" class="modal-demo">
    
   <br> 
<form name="form" novalidate>
  <input type="text" style="width:200px" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="$ctrl.name" required><br>
   <button type="button" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="form.$valid && $ctrl.open()">Save</button>
</form><br>
    <p ng-hide="!$ctrl.msg" class="alert" ng-class="{'alert-success':$ctrl.suc, 'alert-danger':!$ctrl.suc}">{{$ctrl.msg}}</p>
    
</div>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Your Details</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
           
            <p>Are you sure, your name <b>{{$ctrl.name }}</b> is going to submit?
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.ok()">Submit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

with js code:

```
if(confirm("xxx"))
 {
      //do next step
 }
```